# How to understand Mohr diagram?

Tags: geology, structural-geology

Structural geologists use Mohr diagram to evaluate stress on rock's surface, but I find it difficult to understand how this diagram works (Though I am good at math). Where can I find a good explanation of Mohr diagram?

Comment: This is rather an open-ended question. Try to be more specific. Have you already done some reading or research and got stuck? There are so many documents online, and videos in YouTube, it's hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent explanation of the math as related the stresses represented by the Moh'r circle.

http://www.geology.sdsu.edu/visualstructure/vss/htm_hlp/mor_cir.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start understanding Mohr Circles is this Youtube Video about stress on an inclined plane:

https://youtu.be/qDzE2KkMkE0?list=PL2bYAB99Iq4kp5S6o1XEjMP4BVSwCbpLC

From there, check out the other videos of this guy.
But right: this is an open-end question.